# Multiplicity of set

Tags: alloy

Given the below definition:

```
sig Name,Addr{}
sig Book{ addr : Name -> some Addr}

Let Name = { (J),(t), (b)}
Addr = {(1), (2)}
Book = {(bb0)}
```

I was curious that in the relation `addr : Name -> some Addr`, what is the multiplicity of the Name in the second column. Moreover, is the below possible

```
addr = {(bbo, j , 1), (bb0, j, 2)}
```

I trying to learn if j can occur more than once in the second column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, but I only figured it out by trying, you have to define your model properly though:

```
abstract sig Name,Addr{}
abstract sig Book{ addr : Name -> some Addr}

one sig J,t,b extends Name {}
one sig a1,a2 extends Addr {}
one sig bb0 extends Book {}

run { #addr > 3 } for 4 int
```

Execute it and use the evaluator to evaluate `addr` you will see that it contains more than 3 elements, two of which have the same `Name` atom.

Comment: I ran your code and got this : No instance found. Predicate may be inconsistent. 4ms. What went wrong?

Comment: I'm using Alloy 4.1 - works there. Anyway #addr means the number of atoms in the set `addr`.

Comment: Please read the question properly. addr is not a set, but it is a relation. Thus, how can #addr represent the number of atoms in addr when addr contains tuples.

Comment: `addr` is a set of tuples, you're right that technically it doesn't contain atoms, but it still contains elements (which are tuples of atoms). My goal is to find an `addr` with more than 3 elements. And another thing, a set is a unary relation in alloy.